# How to extract Kubernestes PODS mac addresses from annotations object

Tags: kubernetes, annotations, jq

I am trying to extract the mac or ips addresses under metadata.annotations using either kubectl get po in json filter or using jq. other objects are easy to manipulate to get those values.

kubectl get po -o json -n multus|jq -r .items
Under annotations, there is duplication CNI info but it is ok. I like to extract those MAC addresses using jq. it seems to be tricky on this one.

```
[
  {
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
      "annotations": {
        "k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/network-status": "[{\n    \"name\": \"eps-cni\",\n    \"ips\": [\n        \"172.31.83.216\"\n    ],\n    \"default\": true,\n    \"dns\": {}\n},{\n    \"name\": \"ipvlan1-busybox1\",\n    \"interface\": \"net1\",\n    \"ips\": [\n        \"172.31.230.70\"\n    ],\n    \"mac\": \"0a:2d:40:c6:f8:ea\",\n    \"dns\": {}\n},{\n    \"name\": \"ipvlan2-busybox1\",\n    \"interface\": \"net2\",\n    \"ips\": [\n        \"172.31.232.70\"\n    ],\n    \"mac\": \"0a:52:8a:62:5d:f4\",\n    \"dns\": {}\n}]",
        "k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks": "ipvlan1-busybox1, ipvlan2-busybox1",
        "k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks-status": "[{\n    \"name\": \"eps-cni\",\n    \"ips\": [\n        \"172.31.83.216\"\n    ],\n    \"default\": true,\n    \"dns\": {}\n},{\n    \"name\": \"ipvlan1-busybox1\",\n    \"interface\": \"net1\",\n    \"ips\": [\n        \"172.31.230.70\"\n    ],\n    \"mac\": \"0a:2d:40:c6:f8:ea\",\n    \"dns\": {}\n},{\n    \"name\": \"ipvlan2-busybox1\",\n    \"interface\": \"net2\",\n    \"ips\": [\n        \"172.31.232.70\"\n    ],\n    \"mac\": \"0a:52:8a:62:5d:f4\",\n    \"dns\": {}\n}]",
        "kubernetes.io/psp": "eps.privileged"
      },
      "creationTimestamp": "2020-05-24T17:09:10Z",
      "generateName": "busybox1-f476958bd-",
      "labels": {
        "app": "busybox",
        "pod-template-hash": "f476958bd"
      },
      "name": "busybox1-f476958bd-hds4w",
      "namespace": "multus",
      "ownerReferences": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
          "blockOwnerDeletion": true,
          "controller": true,
          "kind": "ReplicaSet",
          "name": "busybox1-f476958bd",
          "uid": "5daf9b52-e1b3-4df7-b5a1-028b48e7fcc0"
        }
      ],
      "resourceVersion": "965176",
      "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/multus/pods/busybox1-f476958bd-hds4w",
      "uid": "0051b85d-9774-4f89-8658-f34065222bf0"
    },
```

**for basic jq,**

```
[root@ip-172-31-103-214 ~]# kubectl get po -o json -n multus|jq -r '.items[] | .spec.volumes'
[
  {
    "name": "test-busybox1-token-f6bdj",
    "secret": {
      "defaultMode": 420,
      "secretName": "test-busybox1-token-f6bdj"
    }
  }
]
```

I can switch the get pod to yaml format then using normal grep cmd.

```
kubectl get po -o yaml  -n multus|egrep 'mac'|sort -u
"mac": "0a:2d:40:c6:f8:ea",
"mac": "0a:52:8a:62:5d:f4",
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] in your question. I don't think anyone's going to read all this, please drop unnecessary details and ask a single, clear, practical, answerable question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the original JSON and using jq's -r command-line option, the following jq filter yields the output shown below:

```
.[]
| .metadata.annotations[]
| (fromjson? // empty)
| .[]
| select(has("mac"))
| {mac}
```

Output:

```
{"mac":"0a:2d:40:c6:f8:ea"}
{"mac":"0a:52:8a:62:5d:f4"}
{"mac":"0a:2d:40:c6:f8:ea"}
{"mac":"0a:52:8a:62:5d:f4"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below command and should get the expected output.

```
cat abc.json | jq -r  '.metadata.annotations."k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks-status" | fromjson | .[].mac '
```

where `abc.json` is your son file.